# Symfony Query Builder partial query throwing circular reference error

Tags: php, rest, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

In my Symfony 4 application there is an API endpoint from which I need information about last `Post` from a given `Thread` and `Author` of this particular `Post`.
This should be the structure of a reponse

```
lastPost: {
  id: 1,
  createdAt: 2018-04-30
  author: {
    id: 1
    nick: 'admin
  }
```

I tried to return this from a repository method in my `PostRepository` using `$this->json->($response)`.

```
public function findLastPostByThreadId($threadId)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p.id, p.createdAt')
            ->addSelect('author.id, author.nick')
            ->innerJoin('p.author', 'author')
            ->where('p.thread = :threadId')
            ->setParameter('threadId', $threadId)
            ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

But if I do that, the `post.id` field gets overwritten by `author.id` and response doesn't have a required structure.

Then I've tried to rewrite this query to partial objects query:

```
public function findLastPostByThreadId($threadId)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p.id, p.createdAt')
            ->addSelect('partial author.{id, nick}')
            ->innerJoin('p.author', 'author')
            ->where('p.thread = :threadId')
            ->setParameter('threadId', $threadId)
            ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'DESC')
            ->setMaxResults(1)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
```

But then it throws error `Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias.`

When I try to make this query based entirely on partial objects

```
public function findLastPostByThreadId($threadId)
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->select('partial p.{id, createdAt}')
        ->addSelect('partial author.{id, nick}')
        ->innerJoin('p.author', 'author')
        ->where('p.thread = :threadId')
        ->setParameter('threadId', $threadId)
        ->orderBy('p.createdAt', 'DESC')
        ->setMaxResults(1)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult();
}
```

I get 
`Uncaught Exception: A circular reference has been detected when serializing the object of class "App\Entity\Section" (configured limit: 1)` even if I don't query for `Section` entity. Section is in one-to-many relation with Thread and I am not requesting any information from this, so I honestly have no idea where this is coming from.

I feel like I'm missing something here or my approach to this is wrong. I guess I could use repository method of `Author` entity to get author details from given post and build a response from it but perhaps there is a way to get this data in single query?

Comment: Are that function located in its entity repository ?

Comment: Yes, they are in repositories.